# Mapping keys to <Esc> in vimrc for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vim

I did the usual:

```
inoremap ;; <Esc>
```

in my .gvimrc/.vimrc file but entering `;;` in insert Mode simply types out the characters `<Esc>`. How should I do this?
 Are there different key names for the Mac keyboard or something that I'm unaware of? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your `'cpo'` setting contains `<`, which disables the recognition of special key codes.

```
:set cpo-=<
```

should fix that (before defining the mapping). But usually, this is caused by running in (vi-) *compatible* mode. So it's better to fix that with

```
:set nocompatible
```

(or just defining a `~/.vimrc`, which implies that setting).